# Was there an explanation to why other Judges helmets didn't interfere with Andersons psychic powers

Tags: movie, dredd

In the very first gun fight scene Dredd asks Anderson as to when she would realize that she had forgotten her helmet, but she states that:

> Sir, a helmet can interfere with my psychic abilities.

But, then when she faces off with the other female judge who is here to kill Dredd and Anderson, Anderson uses her psychic abilities to know that the other judge was here to kill her. She then promptly shot her dead.

### So , what was the explanation for this? Or are we just supposed to think that only when she wears a helmet that her abilities are impeded?

Comment: Wearing a helmet on her own head seems to be the problem, not others wearing theirs.

Comment: @Valorum, thanks. Fixed it.

Answer (score 6):

She says that a helmet **can** interfere with her abilities, not that it consistently and completely blocks them.  So even if it's not just psychological and even if the target wearing a helmet has the same effect as her wearing one, it just means it has the potential to interfere (It's not clear of the details, possibly reducing range, reliability, clarity) but not be a complete shield.

Consider how a helmet can interfere with hearing without rending the wearer completely deaf.

Comment: Out-of-universe, in the comics she mostly takes it off to distinguish her from Judge Dredd, who never takes off his helmet.